# Run ErrorDocument before Mod Rewrite in Htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, error-handling

When I turn rewrite off a 404 goes correctly to Google (used just to test) like it is supposed to.  When it is on it runs the rewrite first and totally ignores the ErrorDocument declaration.  I can't understand why it is doing this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.google.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the below in your `.htaccess` is saying

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     # if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     # if not a directory
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]            # redirect to index.php
```

So, either remove these rules or turn the rewrite engine off.

***EDIT** :*
Permalinks work by catching 404(s) because the link structure physically doesn't exist. `ErrorDocument` doesn't override this because it can still be used as something to fall back upon if `mod_rewrite` decides to ignore a `404`. For example,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     # if not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     # if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/ # & points to wordpress
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]            # redirect to index.php
```

Now, a `domain.com/wordpress/no-such-file.php` would redirect to `/index.php` whereas `domain.com/no-such-file.php` would redirect you to Google (because of `ErrorDocument`).

Comment: Got that...I need that section for Permalinks to work correctly.  I would have thought the ErrorDocument would have redirected prior to this portion.

Comment: Ok, how would I redirect a 404 that is caught by the Permalink then?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Seems since WP takes governance of this .htaccess is pretty well useless when it comes to error handling.

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill Actually, `.htaccess` is what's making WordPress's permalinks work. Those rules (with `-f` and `-d`) are the ones that catch 404(s) and hand it over WordPress's `index.php`. This `php` then processes the source url to find the target content. So, these two kind of work in tandem with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue using

```
if ( is_404() ) {
      wp_redirect( 'static.htm' );
      exit;
   }
```

to customize my 404 further.